# MVC Client Side Validation doing database check

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-mvc-validation

Is there a way how to perform a "database" check through the Client Side Validation in MVC?

I have the following class

```
public class EmailCheck : ValidationAttribute,IClientValidatable
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string sErrorMessage = "Email already exists";
        return new ValidationResult(sErrorMessage); 
    }   

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        ModelClientValidationRule validationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        validationRule.ValidationType = "checkemail";
        validationRule.ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Format";
        validationRule.ValidationParameters.Add("param", "");
        return new List<ModelClientValidationRule> { validationRule };
    }  
}
```

I would like the Client Side Validation to call the "IsValid" method onkeyup/lost focus as well and not just do the regular javascript checks in the "checkemail" javascript function.

The javascript function i have is the following:

```
//Validation for Well-Formed Email
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkemail",
    function (value, element, param) {
        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

        if (!emailReg.test(value))
            return false;

        return true;
    });

jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("checkemail", ["param"], function (options) {    
    options.rules["checkemail"] = options.params.param;
    options.messages["checkemail"] = options.message;
});
```

I would appreciate if anyone could guide me in the right direction or provide a tutorial of something similar.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your model try to use the "Remote" attribute

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx

Comment: Ok thanks, that seems to work.. however when I implement the RemoteAttribute my Client Side Validation javascript checks seem to stop working. Is this normal?

Comment: what kind of checks ? can you elaborate?
RemoteAttribute lets you define the javascript function on your view to be called when someone enters the value in your textbox.

Comment: I had a custom ValidationAttribute check called [EmailCheck] which fired GetClientValidationRules that called the javascript function "checkemail" onkeyup. That function is not being called anymore, or is it possible to call that javascript function using the RemoteAttribute?

Comment: i think there is no need to call javascript function

[Remote("checkemail", "controllername", AdditionalFields = "ID(the id of user)", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "User with same Emailaddress already exists")]

The remote attribute will automatically call the action which checks for existing email  in database.

Comment: No, sorry maybe I didnt explain properly. I first had a client-side validation javascript function called checkmail which was checking in regex whether the user input is in correct format. If that was successful, I wanted it to make use of the RemoteAttribute to do the necessary checks in the database. Is that possible, or should I just combine all into 1 function?

Comment: no need to check with javascript function like for regex,
Just use the [Email] attribute just like remoteattribute and mvc unobtrusive validation will check it on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Rusty is correct, you need to use the Remote attribute in your model

Here is another example with complete detail only for email validation in MVC

[MVC model validation for email from database in asp.net](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1029/mvc-model-validation-for-email-from-database-in-asp-net)